# "Grep-ing" from A to B in hexdump's output

Tags: grep, hexdump

Here is the situation: I have to find in the output from an `hexdump` the bytes between a string A and a string B. The structure of the hexdump is something like:

```
-random bytes
-A + useful bytes + B
-random bytes
-A + useful bytes + B
-random bytes
```

And now, the questions:
- Is it possible to grep "from A to B"? I haven't seen anything like that in the man page or in the internet. I know i can do it manually, but I need to script it.
- Is it possible to show the hexdump output without the line numbers? It seems very reasonable, but I haven't found the way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Perl-like [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match everything between A and B, not including A and B:

```
$ echo 'TEST test A foo bar B test' | grep -oP '(?<=A).*(?=B)'
 foo bar
```

However, taking [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10503751/1258041) into account, you'll have to convert the `hexdump` output to a single string to use `grep`. You can strip off the 'line numbers' on your way:

```
hexdump filename | sed -r 's/\S{5,}//g' | tr '\n' ' '
```

or better

```
hexdump filename | cut -d ' ' -f 2- | tr '\n' ' '
```

Now everything is on one line, so `grep` has to be lazy, not greedy:

```
$ echo 'TEST test A foo bar B test A bar foo B test' | grep -oP '(?<=A).*?(?=B)'
 foo bar 
 bar foo
```

But Michael has a point, maybe you should use something more high-level, at least if you need to do it more than once.

P.S. If you are OK with including A and B in the match, just do

```
$ echo 'TEST test A foo bar B test A bar foo B test' | grep -oP 'A.*?B'
A foo bar B
A bar foo B
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` the *program* only works on one line at a time; you won't be able to get it to work intelligently on a hex dump.

my suggestion: use the regex functionality in perl or ruby or your favorite scripting language, to grep the raw binary data for the string.  This example in ruby:

```
ARGF.read.force_encoding("BINARY").scan(/STR1(.*?)STR2/);
```

This will produce an array containing all the binary strings between occurences of STR1 and STR2.  From there you could run each one through `hexdump(1)`.